# What does "against" mean here?

Tags: word-meaning, word-in-context

> The paver had come up *against* the sidewalk

Does it mean that the paver was pushed up vertically?

Comment: It most likely just means that it abutted the sidewalk, but there isn't enough context to tell, really.

Answer (score 2):

One meaning for when something is [*up against*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/up+against) another thing is that it is pressed firmly onto it.  (In the link, "up against something," definition 1.)

This is particularly true when the two objects involved are inanimate.  If one or both is a living thing, particularly a sentient living thing, then the phrase tends to indicate a conflict instead of simply being closely adjacent.

Answer (score 0):

"Come up" does not mean vertical movement here.  It just means approached (not necessarily even contacting).  "Against" means it actually contacted.